# applicationDidEnterBackground fire popToViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigationcontroller, poptoviewcontroller

I am using the Storyboard, then in my AppDelegate has no navigation controller programming on hand (all normal so far).

Now i need to fire the "applicationDidEnterBackground" I would like my app point to the navigation controller to the first screen (ie) popToView or popToRoot.

I tried to use some means found as:

**EDITED:** - Insert the applicationDidEnterBackgoround Method

```
//*-- BEGIN
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    _mainMenuDelegate = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName: stb_name bundle: nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @ "idMainMenu"];
    [[_window.rootViewController navigationController] popToViewController: _mainMenuDelegate animated: NO];
```

OR

```
     NSArray * = viewContrlls _window.subviews;
     for (int i = 0; i <[viewContrlls count], i + +)
     {
        id obj = [viewContrlls objectAtIndex: i];
        if ([obj isKindOfClass: [MainMenu class]])
        {
            [[_window.rootViewController navigationController] popToViewController: obj animated: YES];
            return;
        }
     }
 } //*-- END
```

But the first does not fire and, the second is just 1 result row and it is not the MainMenu, so do not jump to the ViewController.

My question is: How to do it, knowing that I am using Storyboard?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
NSArray* viewControllers = [[_window.rootViewController navigationController] viewControllers];

for (int i = 0; i < [viewControllers count]; i++)
{
    id obj = [viewControllers objectAtIndex: i];

    if ([obj isKindOfClass: [MainMenu class]])
    {
        [[_window.rootViewController navigationController] popToViewController: obj
                                                                      animated: YES];

        return;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: That's not the problem. The problem is that it no jumps to the viewcontroller. This looping enters 1 time, but this 1 time is not the viewcontroller I want to go, so it dont go. even inserting in hand, as the first block of code, it will not

Comment: I am editing my code and inserting ALL part that I'm trying to do with applicationDidEnterBackgoround

Comment: i edited my question to show what im doing. Your code doesnt work anyway.